# How do I select a count value into temp table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select

I'm trying to select in to a temp table the `cntr_value` for two different counter names with an `instance_name` of `_Total`.  I just can't work out how to do this.

```
INSERT INTO @RESULTS
        (AsOfDate, unsent_log, unrestored_log, instance_name) 
        select @Now, cntr_value, cntr_value, instance_name 
        from master.sys.dm_os_performance_counters 
        where counter_name ='Log Send Queue KB'
        --and counter_name = 'Redo Queue KB'
        and instance_name = '_Total'
        Select * from @results
```

My table looks like this:

```
AsOfDate                      unsent_log    unrestored_log  instance_name
2014-10-30 11:22:25.290        0                    0            _Total
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a while to understand where you were going. Trying to understand @DanGuzman's answer got me on track but I think his answer is way too complicated for what is needed here.

I'd simply go for :

```
INSERT INTO @RESULTS (AsOfDate, unsent_log, unrestored_log, instance_name) 
SELECT @Now, 
       unsent_log = SUM(CASE WHEN counter_name = 'Log Send Queue KB' THEN cntr_value ELSE 0 END),
       unrestored_log = SUM(CASE WHEN counter_name = 'Redo Queue KB' THEN cntr_value ELSE 0 END),
       instance_name 
  FROM master.sys.dm_os_performance_counters 
 WHERE counter_name IN ('Log Send Queue KB', 'Redo Queue KB')
   AND instance_name = '_Total'
 GROUP BY instance_name
```

Which is (IMHO) a lot more readable, easier to extend/maintain and turns out to be a lot more lightweight too (according to the query plan).

Answer (score 1):

You need to either change your logic to use an OR (as the name is either one value OR another) and wrap that clause in brackets due to the rules of precedence:

```
INSERT INTO @RESULTS
    (AsOfDate, unsent_log, unrestored_log, instance_name) 
    select @Now, cntr_value, cntr_value, instance_name 
    from master.sys.dm_os_performance_counters 
    where (counter_name ='Log Send Queue KB' OR counter_name = 'Redo Queue KB')
    and instance_name = '_Total'
```

Alternatively use [IN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx) which is more readable in this situation:

```
INSERT INTO @RESULTS
    (AsOfDate, unsent_log, unrestored_log, instance_name) 
    select @Now, cntr_value, cntr_value, instance_name 
    from master.sys.dm_os_performance_counters 
    where counter_name IN ('Log Send Queue KB', 'Redo Queue KB')
    and instance_name = '_Total'
```

Comment: using the IN answer why do I get two rows in the table? Should I not only have one row containing the time, unsent log, unrestored log and instance_name.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You get 2 rows because you ask for 2 rows. One row that relates to the `Log Send Queue KB` counter and another row that relates to the `Redo Queue KB` counter. If you want both rows 'combined' you probably want to aggregate by using `SUM()` on the values; in which case you'll also need to add `GROUP BY instance_name` to get the syntax correct regardless of the fact that instance_name is (kind of) a constant in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example to get the counter values from 2 different rows using `CROSS APPLY`.

```
INSERT INTO @RESULTS
        ( AsOfDate
        , unsent_log
        , unrestored_log
        , instance_name
        )
        SELECT  SYSDATETIME() AS AsOfDate
              , a.cntr_value AS unsent_log
              , b.cntr_value AS unrestored_log
              , instance_name
        FROM    master.sys.dm_os_performance_counters AS a
                CROSS APPLY ( SELECT    cntr_value
                              FROM      master.sys.dm_os_performance_counters
                                        AS b
                              WHERE     b.counter_name = 'Log Send Queue KB'
                                        AND b.instance_name = '_Total'
                            ) AS b
        WHERE   a.counter_name = 'Redo Queue KB'
                AND a.instance_name = '_Total';
```